# TeX equivalent for LaTeX's \boxed

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

Does anyone have any suggestions for recreating the `\boxed{...}` function from LaTeX in plain TeX? I'm pretty sure it's part of the `amsmath` package for LaTeX.

Comment: From [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.dtx): `\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}`; and you can extract the definition of `\fbox` (and friends) from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can recycle the definition of `\cstok` that you can find in `manmac.tex`:

```
\def\boxed#1{% from \cstok in manmac.tex
  \leavevmode\thinspace
  \hbox{\vrule\vtop{\vbox{\hrule\kern1pt
        \hbox{\thinspace$\displaystyle{#1}$\thinspace}}
      \kern1pt\hrule}\vrule}\thinspace}

$$
a = \boxed{1\over2} = {2\over 4} = \boxed{\root3\of{8^{-1}}}
$$

\bye
```

Adjust the spacing to suit your taste.

[image]

Comment: Interesting to see how the TeX math routines put the `-1` in a visibly too low position.

Comment: @jfbu The argument to `\radical` is typeset in cramped text style (in this case). You can force "non cramped" with an explicit `\textstyle` or `\displaystyle` declaration.

Comment: surprising though that with an overall displaystyle, TeX decides that stuff within a `\root3\of` should be in cramped style, as if this was destined for an inline equation.

Comment: another interesting aspect is that removing the braces around the `#1` would be a very bad idea, as the `\displaystyle` scope is ended by the `\over` in `\boxed{1\over2}` for example.

Comment: @jfbu In my first attempt I missed those braces. ;-) But I immediately realized the mistake because I used `1\over2`.

Comment: comforting to hear that you _sometimes_  need a second attempt... ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I have done `Werner`'s [exercise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96118/tex-equivalent-for-latexs-boxed#comment206296_96118). With the additional braces for use with `\over` as in `egreg`'s answer.

Edit for my first ever non zero use of `\mathsurround`. But sub-formulas (in `\hbox`es) then should be aware and set their own, as is systematic I think in LaTeX/amsmath.

```
\newdimen\fboxsep  \fboxsep3pt
\newdimen\fboxrule \fboxrule.4pt
\newbox\boxedbox

\long\def\boxed #1{\leavevmode
  \setbox \boxedbox = 
  %%\hbox{\kern\fboxsep {\mathsurround0pt $\displaystyle {#1}$}\kern\fboxsep}%
  \hbox{{\mathsurround\fboxsep $\displaystyle {#1}$}}%
  \dimen0=\fboxrule\advance\dimen0\fboxsep\advance\dimen0\dp\boxedbox
  \hbox{\lower \dimen0
           \hbox {%
            \vbox {\hrule height \fboxrule 
             \hbox {\vrule width \fboxrule 
              \vbox {\vskip \fboxsep \box \boxedbox \vskip \fboxsep }%
                    \vrule width \fboxrule }%
                   \hrule height \fboxrule }}}}

$$
a = \boxed{1\over2} = {2\over 4} = \boxed{\root3\of{8^{-1}}}
$$

\bye
```

[image: boxed formulas]
[image: boxedams]

The second being the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

$$
a = \boxed{{1\over2}} = {2\over 4} = \boxed{\root3\of{8^{-1}}}
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: in passing I removed the `\color@begingroup` and `\color@endgroup`, not having checked if package `color` could be used with plain TeX.

Comment: actually, `\hbox{{\mathsurround\fboxsep $\displaystyle {#1}$}}` would give the first ever actual use of `mathsurround` I would have ever done. In `LaTeX2e` they use `\m@th` for `\mathsurround0pt` but here `\mathsurround\fboxsep` would spare some tokens...